# Can someone tell wat is wrong with this query ? I need to get only rows with MIN() instead I am getting all rows

Tags: sql

/* Get the course number(s), the offering number(s), and the number of registered students for the offering(s) that was(were) registered by the fewest number of students of all the offerings.      */

```
select CourseNo , T.*
from Offering O 
inner join
    (select OfferNo, Count(StdNo) as NumOfStudents
    from Enrollment
    group by OfferNo) as T
on O.OfferNo =  T.OfferNO
group by CourseNo , T.OfferNo,NumOfStudents
having NumOfStudents =  min(NumOfStudents);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your intention, you want to select each course in one row, and for each course select only the Offer with MIN(NumOfStudents)?

If so you could use this:

```
SELECT o.CourseNo , t.OfferNo, t.NumOfStudents
FROM Offering o 
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT OfferNo, Count(StdNo) AS NumOfStudents
    FROM Enrollment
    GROUP BY OfferNo) AS t
ON o.OfferNo =  t.OfferNO
WHERE (o.CourseNo, t.NumOfStudents) IN
    (
        SELECT o1.CourseNo , MIN(t1.NumOfStudents) minNumOfStudents
        FROM Offering o1
        INNER JOIN
            (SELECT OfferNo, Count(StdNo) AS NumOfStudents
            FROM Enrollment
            GROUP BY OfferNo) AS t1
        ON o1.OfferNo =  t1.OfferNO
    )
;
```

Or other way is:

```
SELECT o.CourseNo , t.OfferNo, t.NumOfStudents
FROM Offering o 
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT OfferNo, Count(StdNo) AS NumOfStudents
    FROM Enrollment
    GROUP BY OfferNo) AS t
ON o.OfferNo =  t.OfferNO
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT o1.CourseNo , MIN(t1.NumOfStudents) minNumOfStudents
    FROM Offering o1
    INNER JOIN
        (SELECT OfferNo, Count(StdNo) AS NumOfStudents
        FROM Enrollment
        GROUP BY OfferNo) AS t1
    ON o1.OfferNo =  t1.OfferNO
) AS minOffer
ON o.CourseNo = minOffer.CourseNo 
    AND t.NumOfStudents = minOffer.minNumOfStudents;
```

If these queries is not what you need, maybe you should try to explain your intention, with sample data and desire result.

Comment: This query still gives all rows and not the rows with min(NumOfStudents) as you are grouping by CourseNo and OfferNo

Answer (score 0):

You need to select only one row:

```
select o.*
from Offering O inner join
     (select OfferNo, Count(StdNo) as NumOfStudents
      from Enrollment
      group by OfferNo
     ) e
     on O.OfferNo =  e.OfferNO
order by NumOfStudents desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Some databases spell the line clause as `limit 1` or `select top 1`.

Comment: I dont just need 1 row , I need all rows which has value of MIN(COunt(StdNo)